# How to send to batch file multiple arguments of command

Tags: batch-file, parameter-passing, optional-arguments

I want to send parameters inside of existing batch file command.

If I want to delete folder -> will use "`del`" command but also want to add to "`y`", when command is calling.

My question is: How to include parameters of "`del`"?

So, to don't have to pass "`y`" on time when the folder is starting to delete.

Answer (score 2):

try `del /?`

> /Q  Quiet mode, do not give a Yes/No Prompt before deleting.